# Insert image MYSQL based on radio button choice with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, radio-button

I have a website. In this website I can upload images that are then placed into my SQL database. From here I select the images from the database and show them as thumbnails in the photo gallery, when clicked on the image it shows a large version where you can vote/like and comments etc.

Now what I am trying to do is make 3 category pages, basically 3x the photo gallery that shows the thumbnails.

I have 3 different tables in my database where I insert the images in to.
So I copied the photo gallery 3x and the original upload table in the database 3x.
How ever I do not want to create 3 upload.php files for each photo gallery.php file.

What I'm trying to do is have 3 radio button choices on my upload page and with the choice made there, the image gets uploaded into the matching database table (photo1, 2 or 3).

I have been trying to do this with Functions etc. but I just can't get it to work, I am probably doing something really simple, really stupid.

This is the code i have for the radio button and getting the image:

```
    $titel = "Image";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `i268296_studie`.`fotos` ORDER BY foto_ID DESC"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("query error " . mysqli_error($conn) );
    $fotos = array();
    //create array from images in database
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $fotos[] = array('src' => $data['src'], 'id' => $data['foto_ID']);
    }
?>

<section id="upload">                           
                <form method="post" action="upload.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <label for="bestand">Upload image:</label><br><br>
                    <input type="file" name="bestand" id="file"><br><br>
                    <label for="categorie"> Categorie: </label>
                        <input type="radio" name="cat" value="cat1">Portrait
                        <input type="radio" name="cat" value="cat2">Landscape
                        <input type="radio" name="cat" value="cat3">Other
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
                </form>         
            </section>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
            <section class="images">
                <?php 
                //show image thumbnails in photogallery
                foreach($fotos as $foto) 
                { 
                ?>
                <a href="fotoinfo.php?foto_ID=<?php echo $foto['id'];?>"><img class="image" src="<?php echo 'upload/thumb/t_'.$foto['src'];?>"></a>
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>
            </section>
```

The above code I have 3 times (surrounded by HTML etc. as the photo gallery pages).

This is my Upload file (i'll leave most of the thumbnail making code out of it since it's only about the upload part).

```
$titel = "Image";
    $dir='upload/';
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $answer= $_POST['cat'];  
    //Properties of the to be uploaded file
    $fileName = $_FILES["bestand"]["name"]; //file name
    $fileType = $_FILES["bestand"]["type"]; //file format
    $fileSize = $_FILES["bestand"]["size"]; //file size
    $tmpName =  $_FILES["bestand"]["tmp_name"]; //temporary save location for file
    $error = $_FILES["bestand"]["error"]; //error check for file

    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);
        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }   
    //select image from database and check if it already exists
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `i268296_studie`.`fotos` WHERE src = '$fileName'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("query error " . mysqli_error($conn) );
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows > 0)
    {
    echo 'File already exists <br>';
    echo    '<a href="fotogallerij.php">Return to homepage/a>';
    } 
    else
    {   
        // if file doesn't exist move to database, create thumbnail path
        if (move_uploaded_file( $tmpName,$dir.$fileName))
        {
           function category($cat, $titel, $filename)
        {
            global $conn;
            $query = "INSERT INTO `i268296_studie`.`$cat` (`titel`, `src`) VALUES ('$titel', '$fileName')"; //INSERT file into database
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("query error " . mysqli_error($conn) );
        }
            $tname = 't_'.$fileName;
            $tpath = $dir.'thumb/';
            $tnamestate = $tpath.$tname;
            $tptype = substr($fileType,6);
            $ttype = "imagecreatefrom$tptype";
            $name = $fileName;
            $path = $dir;
            $namestate = $path.$name;
            $width = 100;
            $height = 100;
            list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize("$namestate");
            $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
                if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) 
                {
                $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
                } 
                else 
                {
                $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
                }
```

How ever I am staring myself blind on how to fix it or where to place it so it works.
I hope my explanation and question is clear to you guys trying to help me, if not please let me know what I can change or do to help :)

edit:
The errors I am getting are:

```
Undefined variable: titel
Undefined variable: fileName
Undefined variable: conn
mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
```

When I do not pick a radio button but just upload it directly i just get 1 error:

```
Undefined index: cat
```

And it uploads it into the 3rd category

Edit 2:
Changed the function with the global $conn in it.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com) attacks. `addslashes()` is about as useful in preventing those as a tea spoon is for cleaning up a new york snow storm.

Comment: Have you considered just saving them all in the same table and adding a column named "category" where you can designate which category an image is associated with?

Comment: @Marc B Haha okay, it doesn't really matter since the website won't go live to the public anyway it's more as a test for school where i need to implement certain things. I've done everything so far but this somehow i can't get to work though i've tried several things. And i just really like to use radio buttons to make the choice instead of have a separate upload file for each gallery

Comment: @VictorKilo actually I haven't thought about it that much since somehow this seemed easiest to me ^^

Comment: what error do you get? most probably inside the context of the `category()` .. `category3()` function you cannot see the `$conn` variable

Comment: @guido When i replace the $query "INSERT INTO" with the funtions etc. I get loads of errors like: Warning: Missing argument 1 for category1(), Undefined variable: titel
Undefined variable: fileName etc

Comment: @Xereoth pls update the question with additional info, do not use comments

Comment: @guido Updated it with the errors, thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1 function category($cat, $titel, $fileName) {
2     global $conn;         
3     $query = "INSERT INTO `i268296_studie`.`$cat` (`titel`, `src`) VALUES ('$titel', '$fileName')"; 
4     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("query error " . mysqli_error($conn) );
5 }

1: you need these variables from the context calling the function
2: you need the global $conn variable in the function context to be able to run the query
3: use a function parameter for the table to upate call
4: it would be better to return results instead of breaking inside the function
```

The calling code would be like the following:

```
if ($answer == "cat1") {          
     category("fotos", $titel, $fileName);  // or "foto2", $titel, $fileName .....
}
```

Please mind the comments about injection vulnerabilities.
Also read this: http://php.net/manual/it/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I do not get any errors when choosing a category and then uploading it. How ever it doesn't show or upload the image in to the database. I assume that I need to declare $cat and link it to the radio buttons?

Comment: (sorry for the late response, had to take a quick shower since it's really late over here ^^)

It now uploads a image but it doesn't actually load the image (i see a broken image) And i get the error when uploading: 
Undefined variable: fileName 
in the query. which shouldn't happen since it's written correctly etc.

Comment: I think there;s something wrong with the source. In my original database it filled in the source and now it's empty, Anyway I would like to thank you for your help! if you have a solution to the source problem I will take it! else I will try and figure it out myself and still be grateful for your help :)

Comment: about the `undefined variable: fileName` there is a typo in my snippet (filename <-> fileName), pls see updated code (line 1); about other problems in the source code, you can of course create more questions. You will need to be a little more specific about the issues you have to get beeter answers. Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Wow... I feel so stupid!! Usually if I double click on a name in notepad++ it shows all the same variables/names Didn't realize it doesn't check for capital letters. sleep deprived didn't help either ^^ Thanks for your help and next time i will try to be more specific on the question/errors! And thanks again!!